# "Element '<xpath expr="//head">' cannot be located in parent view” in odor 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I am developing a custom module for e-commerce.
To do that I  am creating a component in shop page. Here I require custom css and I write below code in this template

```
<template id="products_categories" inherit_id="website_sale.products" active="False" customize_show="True" name="Shop">
<xpath expr=“//head" position="inside">
    <link href="/extended__ecommerce/static/src/css/module.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</xpath>
```

Then rerun and upgrade module will trigger an exception and I find an internal server error which is in the title of the question.
I could not revert back the previous version by commenting

```
<!--            <xpath expr="." position="inside">-->
<!--                <link href="/extended__ecommerce/static/src/css/module.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
<!--            </xpath>—>
```

Those lines of code.

**I have changed my db to a new db but no change.

How can I back to my previous running version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an invalid character in your XML.  The double quote in `<xpath expr="` is not a real double quote.  Notice how your code is highlighted poorly in the code macro.  I changed it here, can you see the difference?

```
<template id="products_categories" inherit_id="website_sale.products" active="False" customize_show="True" name="Shop">
<xpath expr="//head" position="inside">
    <link href="/extended__ecommerce/static/src/css/module.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</xpath>
```

Notice how `//head` is highlighted correctly here but not in your post.

Comment: I changed the code. still, the error happens. now the point is how to revert to the previous version?

Comment: the error is                                                                                                                   
 Error to render compiling AST
TypeError: _get_asset_nodes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'src'
Template: web.layout
Path: /t/html/head/t[7]
Node: <t t-call-assets="web.assets_common" t-js="false"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
<template id="products_categories" 
inherit_id="website_sale.products" active="False" 
customize_show="True" name="Shop">
<xpath expr=". " position="inside">
<link 
 href="/extended__ecommerce/static/src/css/module.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
</xpath>
```